# jQuery CSS not applying

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any reason that this CSS shouldn't work?

```
$('.selector').css(
            'background-color', '#74d04c',
            '-webkit-box-shadow','inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
            '-moz-box-shadow','inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
            'box-shadow','inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
            'border','1px solid #4c8932'
            );
```

The only one that is showing is the background-color.

Comment: Which browsers have you tested this with? (As CSS3 does not work in every browser.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) takes either a property name and value, or a map. You can do this:

```
$('.selector').css('color','blue');
```

...or this:

```
$('.selector').css({'color':'blue', 'left':'100px'});
```

The problem is that you're mixing the two approaches. Instead, try it like this:

```
$('.selector').css({
  'background-color':'#74d04c',
  '-webkit-box-shadow':'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
  etc...
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you're supposed to add the different rules using javascript object notation, not as a huge array.

Update: Yep - it accepts either two string parameters (key, value), or a map of key-value pairs. Source: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

If you're applying multiple rules, you have to pass the css function a JS object. [More details](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2).

$("selector").css({"background-color": "red", "color": blue});

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('.selector').css({
    'background-color' : '#74d04c',
        '-webkit-box-shadow' : 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
        '-moz-box-shadow':'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
        'box-shadow':'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
        'border':'1px solid #4c8932'
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EeYMh/)

Answer (score 1):

Fix your syntax.

```
$('.selector').css({'background-color' : '#74d04c',             
                    '-webkit-box-shadow' : 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',             
                    '-moz-box-shadow' : 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',             
                    'box-shadow' : 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',             
                    'border' : '1px solid #4c8932'});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set multiple CSS attrs like that, you need to [use a map](http://api.jquery.com/css/#example-1-2):

```
$('.selector').css({
            'background-color':'#74d04c',
            '-webkit-box-shadow':'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
            '-moz-box-shadow':'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
            'box-shadow':'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dbf383, inset 0px -1px 1px #58c43a',
            'border':'1px solid #4c8932'
            });
```